# WPF - Can I style a TextBox's text based on input criteria?

Tags: wpf, textbox, foreground

I have a Textbox which needs to save a server address. I would like for the Http:// or Https:// part of the entered text to be a different color than the rest of the link - without creating more than one textbox. Is this possible?

Example of what I want

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odh1L.jpg]

Comment: No, you can't. Either use a `RichTextBox` or fake it by putting a `TextBlock` in front of the `TextBox` and wrap both into a common `Border`. This results in a static _http_  prefix. If you don't want this, the use the `RichTextBox`, parse the input in order to index the scheme component (e.g. https), then select the text range from 0 to index and set the foreground for this range.

Comment: I'll try implementing the RichTextBox instead. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Have you considered a separate combobox for the http / https part?